# Json data return really messy when implement function from other class instead of working directly in a single function

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have a function that return a list of Devices that related to a User. Device is in a relationship many-to-many with a Room. Room has a relationship of many-to-1 with Location and Location has relationship of many-to-many with User. If I run all the query inside a function, json data return beautifully but when I separate it into many function such as I query a list of Location from a User, then from those List of Location, I use it to get list of device that related to that Location then Add them all inside a list. This method return me a very ugly json. I can make them beautiful again by turn off LazyLoading but I want to understand why this happen.

This is my code to query everything inside a single function.

```
        var deviceTotal = db.Devices.Where(x => x.deviceId > 0).ToList();
        deviceTotal.Clear();
        var locationList = db.Locations.Where(a => a.UserLocations.Any(b => b.userId == 3)).ToList();
        int locationCount = locationList.Count();
        for (int i = 0; i < locationCount; i++)
        {
            var currentLocation = locationList.ElementAt(i);
            var roomList = db.Rooms.Where(x => x.locationId == currentLocation.locationId).ToList();
            var roomCount = roomList.Count();
            for (int y = 0; y < roomCount; y++)
            {
                var currentRoom = roomList.ElementAt(y);
                var devicee = db.Devices.Where(a => a.RoomDevices.Any(b => b.roomId == currentRoom.roomId)).ToList();
                deviceTotal.AddRange(devicee);
            }
        }
        return Ok(deviceTotal);
```

Result:

[image: Beautiful Json]

And this is separate code in different function

```
        var deviceTotal = db.Devices.Where(x => x.deviceId > 0).ToList();
        deviceTotal.Clear();
        try
        {
            //Get related location for user
            int currentUserID = 3;
            var locationList = db.Locations.Where(a => a.UserLocations.Any(b => b.userId == currentUserID)).ToList();
            if (locationList != null)
            {
                int locationCount = locationList.Count();
                for (int i = 0; i < locationCount; i++)
                {
                    var currentLocation = locationList.ElementAt(i);
                    var devices = deviceService.getDeviceListFromSingleLocation(currentLocation);
                    deviceTotal.AddRange(devices);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
        return Ok(deviceTotal);

    public List<Device> getDeviceListFromSingleLocation(Location currentLocation)
    {
        var deviceTotal = db.Devices.Where(x => x.deviceId > 0).ToList();
        deviceTotal.Clear();

        var roomList = db.Rooms.Where(x => x.locationId == currentLocation.locationId).ToList();
        var roomCount = roomList.Count();
        for (int y = 0; y < roomCount; y++)
        {
            var currentRoom = roomList.ElementAt(y);
            var devicee = db.Devices.Where(a => a.RoomDevices.Any(b => b.roomId == currentRoom.roomId)).ToList();
            deviceTotal.AddRange(devicee);
        }
        return deviceTotal;
    }
```

Ugly Json:

[image: Ugly Json]

Comment: Aside from anything else, in `getDeviceListFromSingleLocation` why are you querying the database and then immediately discarding the results (`deviceTotal.Clear()`)? I'd also suggest using a join rather than performing one query per room...

Comment: Because deviceTotal was mean to be an empty list of device that I will constantly add new list into it. C# won't allow me to have a null variable and I need a variable with the structure of device list.

Comment: Querying the database and then clearing the list is a *really* expensive way to create an empty list. `var deviceTotal = new List<Device>();` is far, far cheaper. (But performing a single query using the database to do the joins would also be cheaper than performing N+1 queries...)

Comment: Thanks. I just think of that. It would surely help me improving my code.